# API availability out of preview

Tags: api, office365

I'm using the Office365 API presently in preview but I'd like to know if anyone has visibility of when the APIs will be out of preview, ready for production use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We currently don't have a publically available date for the APIs to come out of preview. When we do, we'll be sure to announce it via the [Office dev blog.](http://blogs.office.com/dev)